# can someone explain meaning of a&=b?

Tags: python

my problem is a &= b
after searching internet for a while i found that its a bitwise and operator but cant figure out what its doing in this program

> ```
> x = int(input("Insert first number: "))
> y = int(input("Insert second number: "))
>
> if x>y:
>     x,y =x,y
> elif x<y :
>     x,y= y,x
>
> while x != 0 and y != 0:
>     if x > y:
>         x %= y
>     else:
>         y &= x
>
> GCD = x + y
> print("The greatest common divisor = ",GCD)
> ```

Comment: provided program does not compute GCD

try sample (3, 5) -> gcd should be 1, this gets stuck in infinite loop

check https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gcd-in-python/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x %= y means  x = x % y  --- this is mod operator

x &= y means  x = x & y  --- this is bit-wise "and" operator.
First two operands (integers) are converted into binary form. Then, bit-wise and operation is performed.

Answer (score 2):

@angelogro should answer your question.

I supplement on it.

```
"&" And Operator will keep all common `1` in two digits.
```

eg.

```
3 = 0b011
7 = 0b111
```

3 & 7 will keep the last two `1`
the answer should be 3.

beside this, the program you sent it got problem , u can try test case with

```
x= 17 y = 5
```

for finding GCD
sample program from
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/gcd-in-python/
please check it out

```
def computeGCD(x, y): 
  
   while(y): 
       x, y = y, x % y 
  
   return x
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a the binary operation AND where the result of `y&x` is written to `y`. [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND) is an explanation to bitwise AND.

Example:

```
x=3
y=7

print(f"x in binary: {bin(x)}; y in binary: {bin(y)}")
```

Outputs: `x in binary: 0b11; y in binary: 0b111`

```
y&=x

print(f"x in binary: {bin(x)}; y in binary: {bin(y)}")
```

Outputs: `x in binary: 0b11; y in binary: 0b11`